# Why JALR can write register zero in risc-v?

Tags: assembly, riscv

Why is the instruction `jalr` able to write register zero?

I am simulating a cpu, and I get a instruction `00008067` in hex

Its imm is 0, rs1 is 1, and rd is 0.

`jalr` need do following:

`rd = PC+4` and `PC = imm+rs1`

But isn't register 0 can't be modified, it should always be zero?

Comment: `r0` is like a "sink" that discards writes when you don't want to modify any of the other registers.  Making it illegal to use the zero register as an output operand would defeat half the purpose, e.g. of `add r0, r0, r0` being a NOP, or implementing `jr` in terms of `jalr` and discarding the return address output.

Comment: Why do we write something which can't access(output) in register zero?

Comment: You *can* write to `r0`, it just doesn't change the value.  You do that *because* you don't want to modify any registers, but there isn't a separate opcode with no output operand.  So you use `r0` as the output, resulting in no change to any registers.